# how to play an amr audio,QMediaPlayer not support?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmediaplayer

```cpp
QMediaPlayer* _player = new QmediaPlayer(this);    
QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.amr");
_player->setMedia(url);
_player->play();
```

`_player->errorString()` is DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 80040266.

Do i need to convert amr to mp3 and then use qmediaplayer to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formats supported by `QMediaPlayer` depends on the backend you use, in windows uses `DirectShow` and the formats supported formats found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), unfortunately the `amr` format is not in the list.

For more information you can read [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57675/which-file-formats-or-codecs-does-qmediaplayer-support/3).